# Can't boot in Windows and can't run boot-repair after update to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

After update to 14.04 I can't boot in Windows 8 and in GRUB I have only 3 options instead of 7 I had previously. Also I tried to repair boot but I can't.
Running: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update` returns me:

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

 W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Yeah it was the solution for running boot-repair thanks. But still can't boot in Windows 8.

Comment: Why not ? can you describe the problem in more detail ?

Comment: Befor upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 everything was working great. But after upgrade I right away noticed that in grub I lost a few options in what I can boot. Today I tried to boot in Windows but it doesn't work (will go and try again and write what it says on screen before it returns me back to grub).

Comment: Boot options are: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu and Windows boot manager (on /dev /sda2). After hitting Windows boot option I get Error: failed to load files or something like that (it is on screen for less than 1 second) and returns me to GRUB boot options.

Comment: With Windows it boots with uefi, try selecting which OS to boot in your bios.

Comment: Tried this method as soon as I found out that I can't boot and is not working.

Comment: If you are having a problem booting, start a new question and post the url given to you by boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to boot into windows? 
Do you have a Ubuntu live cd previous to the 14.04? You can run boot-repair from there.

It seems to me only grub is affected.

Also, there is a program called grub-customizer that allows you to edit manually the grub entries ( haven't tried it in 14.04, only 13.10 ).

You can also download the boot-repair cd and boot from it, but if you have a previous Ubuntu live cd it would be faster to use what you already have.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow as tonight I don't have Live cd at me here. Also will report as soon as I am finished.

Comment: I ran Ubuntu 13.10 from usb and did boot-repair and nothing is better. Still getting error reading file. Did get this http://paste.ubuntu.com/7299246/ link. If anyone can check it out. To me it looks good as far as I understand it. And could you tell me what to do with grub-customizer :)... Thanks